# What does "might" exactly mean in the following excerpt?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, archaicisms, early-modern-english, phrase-meaning

This is a excerpt from Le Morte d'Arthur by Sir Thomas Malory, and I want to know the exact meaning of *might* regarding the context. Some say by *might* we mean:

> being allowed to

and some say it means:

> being able to

Of course we are all aware of the first meaning but relating to the later one, I couldn't find anything related. Here is the excerpt:

> And thereupon Isoud fell down in a swoon, and so lay a great while And
>   when she *might* speak she said: My lord Sir Tristram, blessed be God ye
>   have your life, and now I am sure ye shall be discovered by this
>   little brachet, for she will never leave you.

Comment: i think the meaning is being able to, but i couldn't find anything either.

Comment: A Google search for "when he might speak, he" returns very few relevant hits, mainly archaic. Two are: "...anon Sir Bors lost his countenance,
and for kindness and pity he might not speak, but wept
tenderly a great while.  And then when he might speak
he said thus: ..." // "Thereat in his turn Ralph fell a laughing, and when he might speak he said: “What needeth the lord of all these spears to beg off his service to the poor wandering knight?”

Comment: There seems to be an intermediate sense of the modal: 'not be constrained not to by considerations of propriety'. If Sir Bors above hadn't been incapacitated by his weeping, he would probably still have maintained a respectful silence for some time: _and for kindness and pity he might not speak for a great while. And then when he might speak he said thus:_

Comment: Oh, and another example: _who gave Himself for our sins so that He might rescue us from this present evil age, according to the will of our God and Father, ..._
- New American Standard Version (1995)

Comment: If she was "in a swoon", she was, presumably, *unable* to speak initially, which tends to suggest the meaning "And when she *was able to* speak she said:".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth:  In the NIVEC (New International Version Exhaustive Concordance), the word "might" is considered  an AIT word (Assist In Translation) in most instances, since the verb in the original Greek would be inflected to include the notion of "might," whereas in English there is a need for a "helping verb" for an equivalent meaning.

Comment: @ rhetorician: But _which_ notion of 'might'!? (Or rather, the notion of which sense of 'might'?) God 'being allowed to' sounds rather illogical - who is there to forbid Him? However, He _is_ 'constrained' by His own character and principles.

Comment: Wowwww, guys i really appreciate your comments and help, thank you very much every one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=might) clearly points at "being able to" or "have the strength to"

**might (v.)**

> Old English mihte, meahte, originally the past tense of may (Old English magen "to be able"), thus "*may-ed." See may (v.). The first record of might-have-been is from 1848.

**might (n.)**

> Old English miht, earlier mæht "might, bodily strength, power, authority, ability," from Proto-Germanic *makhti- (cf. Old Norse mattr, Old Frisian, Middle Dutch, Dutch macht, Old High German maht, German Macht, Gothic mahts), Germanic suffixed form of PIE root *magh- (1) "be able, have power" (see may (v.)).

In Danish we have "at magte" where "*Jeg magter det ikke*" means I do not have the strength or capability to do it

Comment: The Danish verb is derived from the noun _magt_ (might, power), though, and is not directly comparable. The Icelandic verb _mega_ (an exact cognate to Old English _magen_ mentioned in the etymology above), however, still retains the meaning of ‘be able to’ in some contexts—one of which is indeed a translation of the Danish phrase: _Ég má mín ekki við það_ means ‘I can’t handle it’ or ‘I can’t manage it’.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not know the book, and therefore cannot give you a conclusive answer.

It is possible that might is used as 'being able to,' as she might have recovered from the shock.

But it is also possible, that she is only now being allowed to speak, and thus changing the meaning to 'being allowed to.'

I hope that this answer was helpful